# android dcim folder path

Tags: android, gallery, directory

is there a way to get the DCIM path (it may be on sdcard or on device)on Api level 7? Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM is available only from api level 8

Answer (score 7):

I think the DCIM directory is never on the internal storage (My HTC Legend won't even take photo's without an sd-card present). The Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM variable is just the String "DCIM" [ref](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/os/Environment.java#180).

The reason for storing images in /DCIM is compatibility with cardreaders (printers for example) who expect pictures to be available in /DCIM, so I don't think it makes sense to have it on internal storage.

Anyway the folder on external storage (sd-card) can be accessed like this:

```
File rootsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dcim = new File(rootsd.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM");
```

Comment: I have device ZTE 880E (4.0.4). It have internal storage (`/mnt/sdcard2`). If I don't insert external SD-card, then pictures/movies from camera saved to internal store: `/mnt/sdcard2/DCIM`. If I insert SD-card (it mounted to `/mnt/sdcard`), then camera data saved to sdcard: `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM`. But in both cases `getExternalStorageDirectory` return /mnt/sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118048/android-dcim-folder-path)

Alternatively, You can save the picture to any path on the sdcard - preferably create a directory for your app. The media scanner in android will pick up your file and add it automatically to the library.

You can force the device to scan the file for immediate results with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414955/trigger-mediascanner-on-specific-path-folder-how-to) (don't know if thats the recommended approach)