# Path of Images taken with the camera in android 2.1

Tags: android

I have problem in accessing the exact path of images saved by camera in android 2.1 or lower API.  I used this Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
but it works for API level > 7.

Answer (score 0):

For API < 8 you will probably will have to do what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118048/android-dcim-folder-path/5118447#5118447) guy suggest.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? It bight be possible to it in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getCanonicalPaht()` will give you the directory the camera app uses. I used it in my application and it is API 8.

Comment: Wrong, getExternalStorageDirectory() is API 1. getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() is however API 8 and I believe you meant that.