# Trigger MediaScanner without an entire class

Tags: java, android, refresh, media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trigger mediascanner on specific path (folder), how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414955/trigger-mediascanner-on-specific-path-folder-how-to)

Is their a way to trigger the mediascanner without adding an entire class.

I tried something like this

```
MediaScannerConnection mScanner;

File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String sdcard2 = sdcard.toString();

mScanner.connect();
mScanner.scanFile(sdcard2+"/DCIM/Camera/", "*/*");
```

But this isn't working, how to make this work?
I want to scan a path or an image.