# Android does not show file in Downloads folder when looking for it from PC

Tags: android, flutter

I wrote a file in Download directory (internal memory) on my phone using Flutter application. I cheched file properties on phone and the file is not hidden, i.e. the file is visible on the smartphone. But when I check this folder from a regular computer the file is not present there.

Comment: You did not inform the media store about your new file. Do it or reboot your device.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Android Studio, connect your phone to the PC and run your app. then open device file explorer.

your app data should be in data/package name/ data

let me know if this works

Comment: that happes even if I write the file from the already installed app

Comment: could you find it from Android Studio?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593066/android-save-file-to-downloads-that-can-be-viewed-later

Comment: hi @MohammadMoeinGlochin , if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.