# Refresh gallery in android kitkat

Tags: android

How to refresh gallery the in android kitkat ?

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

I tried with the above, but its not refreshing in android 4.4. How to refresh the gallery when add/delete the images programatically ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File("folderPATH", "fileName");
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    appContext.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
} else {
    appContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "FOLDER_TO_REFRESH")));
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following technique to update all files present in a single folder:

```
for (File child : fileFolder.listFiles()) {
    if (child.isFile()) {
        fName = child.getName();
        Log.d("MyTag", "Scanning >> " + child.getName());

    MediaScannerConnection
        .scanFile( MyActivity.this,
        new String[] { "path/of/our/folder" + fName },
        null,  new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
              public void onScanCompleted(
              String path, Uri uri) {
                 Log.i("ExternalStorage",  "Scanned " + path + ":");
                 Log.i("ExternalStorage",  "-> uri=" + uri);
              }
        });
    }
}
```

Source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147536/how-to-trigger-mediascan-on-nexus-7)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to add/ refresh gallery images.

```
    String version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        String mCurrentPhotoPath = "file://"
                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AppDirectory"; // image
                                                                                // is
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // created
                                                                                // file
                                                                                // image
        File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    } else {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    /*
                     * (non-Javadoc)
                     * 
                     * @see android.media.MediaScannerConnection.
                     * OnScanCompletedListener
                     * #onScanCompleted(java.lang.String, android.net.Uri)
                     */
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Scanned ................" + path);
                    }
                });
    }
```