# Cannot find storage/emulated/0/ folder of Nexus 7 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, adb, nexus-7

Nexus 7, Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse Juno

Nexus 7 has been set developer mode.
And in Eclipse I can see lists in "File Explorer" for Android.

I can see storage/emulated/legacy

But I can not see storage/emulated/0/ folder

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I used your solution. I also accepted your answer. Thank you. : )

Comment: Thanks :D Though just as a heads up, you upvoted the answer but didn't accept it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have had the same problem as well. Found the answer in a comment on a seperate stack overflow question so credit goes to the author.

> everything is a link to /storage/emulated/legacy anyway, which itself is a link to /mnt/shell/emulated/0 which contains the file. – moonlightcheese Dec 7 '12 at 13:55

So check out that directory through the Android file explorer, and you will have your files.

Edit: Here is a link to the original comment: [Nexus 4 not showing files via MTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737261/nexus-4-not-showing-files-via-mtp#comment18920361_13756186)

Comment: this works, but is not very satisfying. when I call Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() I expect to get a path I can work with, but this path is not available via adb (shell, pull, push). I don't like it :/ . I might have to create a dirty workaround for nexus 4 and 7.

Comment: I have found a (not that dirty) solution to get the right path via shell command: adb shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Can you link to the separate question so I can give props to him too.

Comment: @Turbo There you go, thanks for mentioning that. Link to the actual comment is much better than just copy pasting it and giving cred :)

Comment: Another solution is rebooting the device. Doing this the folder appears to me. It's not so satisfying too, but it works.