# File object can't find the file when there is one

Tags: java, android, android-networking, android-file

In my app After user clicks on a button ,the download manager starts to download a file from internet and saving it to the internal sd card using this code:

```
void startDownload()
    {
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).mkdirs();        
        download_req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
        .setTitle(PersianReshape.reshape("Downloading"))
        .setDescription(PersianReshape.reshape("currently downloading the file..."))
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() , packageId + ".sqlite");
        download_ID = mgr.enqueue(download_req);
    }
```

After it is downloaded, I plan to check its existance everytime app runs with this code:

```
String DatabaseAddress =
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
"/ee.sqlite";
File file = new File(DatabaseAddress);
Log.d("PATH File: ", DatabaseAddress);
if (file.exists()){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now when I run this code it returns "not found" message whereas the file is already there (I checked its existance using a file manager).

the device I test on is nexus 7 and path used in saving the download file is: /storage/emulated/0/ee.sqlite

ee.sqlite is the filename of downloaded file.

/storage/emulated/0/ is the default path returned by app

Permissions added to manifest for this code are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Q: Why does file.exists() returns false when there is a file?**

**UPDATE:
WHEN I USE HARDCODE**

```
File temp = new File("/sdcard/storage/emulated/0/", "ee.sqlite");
```

**it works but when I use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() it doesn't.**

Comment: Try to print `file.getAbsolutePath()`: they (files) may be in different directories. Another possible reason is permissions, but I don't think it's because of permissions.

Comment: file.getAbsolutePath returns the same address as file.getPath().

Comment: I mean that the destination path of the download and the path that you check for existence may be different.

Comment: BTW, did you mention that in your code you use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() in one place and getExternalStorageDirectory() in the other?

Comment: If they are the same, `Log.d("~~~", "----" + new File(file.getAbsolutePath()).exists())` should print true while `Log.d("~~~", "----" + file.exists())` prints false. This would be absurd, and also would mean a bug.

Comment: By the way, sometimes spaces may creep in paths. Please print the path as `Log.d("~~~","path=["+path+"]");`

Comment: I used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() in both classes of my code.

Comment: I did the log and they both return false.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41397/discussion-between-user1290467-and-18446744073709551615)

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize the `File` like this:

**Updated:** 
This is just because of the separator missing there:

```
 public static File getExternalStorageDirectory() {
    return EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY;
}
```

and EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY is:

```
private static final File EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY
        = getDirectory("EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "/sdcard");

static File getDirectory(String variableName, String defaultPath) {
    String path = System.getenv(variableName);
    return path == null ? new File(defaultPath) : new File(path);
}

String baseDir = EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY ;
String fileName = "ee.sqlite";

// Not sure if the / is on the path or not
File file = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);
if (file.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**2nd Possibilites:** As you are running it in emulator you have to make sure you have external storage enabled Like this:

In Eclipse, go to Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager. Select the appropriate AVD and then click Edit. 
[image: Window - Android SDK and AVD Manager]

Make sure you have SD card support enabled. If you do not, click the "New" button and select the "SD Card Support" option.

[image: Edit screen]

Comment: How you gave the dirName and fileName?

Comment: yes ,String dirName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); and String fileName = "ee.sqlite";

Comment: Tried it but it still doesn't work. only hard coded string works.

Comment: This is just because of the separator. You didn't gave there. I have mentioned it in my updated section and updated my answer

Comment: See my 2nd possibilties section

Comment: I'm testing the app on 2012 Nexus 7 running JB 4.3.

Comment: What is returning by 'Log.d("PATH File: ", DatabaseAddress);'

Comment: Emulator returns: /storage/sdcard/ee.sqlite and nexus 7 returns: /storage/emulated/0/ee.sqlite

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737261/nexus-4-not-showing-files-via-mtp

Comment: As you can see in nexus 7 you didnt get any option like /sdcard right? So do onething like call the external storage like my updated answer and let me know it helps you or not?

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't help. the only way that could make it work is adding the string "/sdcard/". --> File file = new File("/sdcard/" + dirName + File.separator , fileName); Works but yours doesn't.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41396/discussion-between-user1290467-and-andru)

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it to work by changing the File object.

The solution is to change the File object to the following:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + dirName + File.separator , fileName);
```

where dirName is:

```
String dirName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

and fileName is:

```
String fileName = "ee.sqlite";
```

so I could easily check whether file exist or not using my criteria function.

```
if (file.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I like to thank @andru for helping me.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make much sense, you're including two times the absolute path to the external storage directory.