# How to create Directory and See it on Computer

Tags: java, android, directory

I try to create directory on Tablet and want to see it.

I create directory with this code

```
public void createDirectory(String sDirectoryName) {
  File direct = getDir(sDirectoryName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  File fileWithinMyDir = new File(direct, "myfile");

  if(!direct.exist()) {
     System.out.println("Directory created");
  }
  else {
     System.out.println("Directory not created");
  }
}
```

I see everytime Directory created, But when I search Folder in file system, I can not see it. How can I make it visible. Am I making wrong?

EDIT:

I gave all permission on manifest. And I tried this code too

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+sDirectoryName);

        if(!direct.exists())
        {
             if(direct.mkdir())
             {
                 System.out.println("Directory created");
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Directory not created");
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory not created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
        }
```

But this is not working for me too.

EDIT:
For refreshing I use this code.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: because Android uses the MTP protocol for USB connections sometimes a file or folder just wont show because everything is cached and may need a refresh.

More info: [Nexus 4 not showing files via MTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737261/nexus-4-not-showing-files-via-mtp)

Answer (score 0):

To create a dir:

```
if(!direct.exist()) {
   if (direct.mkdir())
      Log.i(TAG, "Directory created");
   else
      Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create directory");
}
```

and don't forget permissions in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Check for `.mkdir()` result!

Answer (score 0):

File does not create a file if it doesn't exist. It just stores the path to it. Your if statement shows it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public void createDirectory(String sDirectoryName)
            {    
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), sDirectoryName);
                                if (!file.exists()) {
                                    file.mkdirs();

                            }
    }
```

Comment: I want too see Folder on my computer. Maybe its working correct but I would like to see it for saving files.

Comment: internal sd card and then search for your folder

Comment: I have't got sd card. I connect it to the computer and try to search. Basicaly I want to see it on my computer

Comment: on your computer when you attach the device thier create a portable device folder in the window explorer

Comment: open it and search for your folder

Comment: I did it. But I can not see. I have Android 4.1.2 Version.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to create directory.

```
public void createDirectory(String sDirectoryName) {
  File direct = getDir(sDirectoryName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  File fileWithinMyDir = new File(direct, "myfile");

  if(!direct.exist()) {
     direct.mkdirs();
     System.out.println("Directory created");
  }
  else {
     System.out.println("Directory not created");
  }
}
```

Add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your manifeist have the following permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And in code

```
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+DOC_FOLDER_NAME);

    // create directory if not exists 
    if(!directory.exists())
    {
        if(directory.mkdirs()) //directory is created;
            Log.i(" download ","App dir created");
        else 
            Log.w(" download ","Unable to create app dir!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in manifest add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and this for java file:

```
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dirName");

if(!myDirectory.exists()) {                                 
  myDirectory.mkdirs();
}
```

to delete it:

```
 myDirectory.delete();
```

and this for File object for the parent directory:

```
 //create a File object for the parent directory

 File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
 // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
 wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
 // create a File object for the output file
 File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, filename);
 // now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is confusing :

```
if(!direct.exist()) { // If directory does not exist
     System.out.println("Directory created"); // Directory created not true
}
```

As just creating a `File` object it will not create directory the code should be:

```
if(!direct.exist()) { // If directory does not exist
     direct.mkdir(); // Create directory
     System.out.println("Directory created");
}
else {
     System.out.println("Directory not created");
}
```

Also make sure to add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your application.

Additionally its suggested not to use [`System.out.println`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220547/why-doesnt-system-out-println-work-in-android) in Android as On the emulator and most devices `System.out.println` gets redirected to LogCat and printed using `Log.i()`. This may not be true on very old or custom Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue not on the line 
`File direct = getDir(sDirectoryName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

According to the documentation context.MODE_PRIVATE will only be visible within the app itself another program or user ID won't be able to find it.

try:

`File direct = getDir(sDirectoryName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);`

or

`File direct = getDir(sDirectoryName, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html