# Issues saving a textfile on Android device for later access

Tags: android, text-files, android-sdcard, fileoutputstream, android-file

I need some functionality where I can save a text file and an image in my device, that can somehow be accessed without the application.

For the text file I would just like to write my database in it. I need for the user to be able to later access that file. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it? As of now, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523), which sends me the message that is working. The issue is,  cannot find the file. Where would it be? Or am I just missing something?

Here is my code for writing the file (which was as the tutorial suggested):

```
     try {
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/documents");
                dir.mkdirs();
                File myFile = new File(dir, "mysdfile.txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append("I am writing something on the file as a test!");
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Thanks!

Edit: just to add a couple more details, the directory I am getting from the

```
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

is /storage/emulated/0 is this what is expected? Or is there something wrong that I may be missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder

Comment: @Salem I saw that thread, but the solutions presented didn't work for me. Or they did, but I still have no idea how to access the directory in which the file is saved to.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out (well sortav...) Turns out it was the good and old "restart your device"

Source from where I found the solution: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737261/nexus-4-not-showing-files-via-mtp#comment18920361_13756186)

Comment: Maybe you need `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE).setData(fileUri));`

Comment: That made it work perfectly! Thank you so much @Gak2