# get folder names inside special directory

Tags: android, directory

I want to get folder names inside the special directory.

for example : inside `/storage/sdcard/DCIM` there is two sub folder name `100ANDRO` and `Camera`

How can i achieve this ?

i tried :

```
ArrayList<File> files;
File directory = new File("/storage/sdcard/DCIM");

    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            files.add(file);
        }
    }
```

but i get `NullPointerException`

Comment: This path `/storage/sdcard/DCIM` is not valid. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118048/android-dcim-folder-path)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein My question was not duplicate of what you marked

Comment: `i get NullPointerException` tells me that it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()` instead of `/storage/sdcard`
Try this :

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String SD_PATH = extStore.getAbsolutePath()+"DCIM";
```

You need permissions to read from sdcard:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right but the problem didn't change .

Comment: again same problem ! is there any permission needed ?

Comment: Didn't you add permissions??

Comment: My mistake :) Thank you

Comment: problem was with permission?

Comment: ya it was the problem and of course the path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93960/discussion-between-behrooz-and-jas).

Answer (score 0):

you need to init files `ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();`
and yes Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` for directory path

Comment: thanks , i init files and use Envirement for directory and same problem